# How do I clean a moldy rice cooker heating element?

Tags: cleaning, rice-cooker

There's a pretty large patch of white and green mold on the heating element of my rice cooker, near the magnet. Is there a way to remove it? It's grown to the point of bumpy.

It seems that my brother forgot to properly clean the underside of the inner pot this whole time

Comment: Are you sure it is mold and not corrosion - iron and copper can turn into green, blue, white salts if corroding from something else than water...

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think corrosion would create new substance, in this case the bumps, therefore I think it's mold. I'm also not certain of the metal used for the heating element

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a moist rag with just dish washing soap. Then a moist rag with bleach.  Then let it air dry for a day.